# LOAD XML INFILE and child column

Tags: mysql, xml, load

I have source XML file with following structure:

```
<prices>
    <price>
        <code>AD1450.150.1</code>
        <startdate>2011-10-15</startdate>
        <enddate>2011-11-25</enddate>
        <rentalprice>1691.00 </rentalprice>
        <minrentalprice>860.00 </minrentalprice>
        <maxrentalprice>1217.00 </maxrentalprice>
        <services>
            <service>
            <code>BG</code>
            <serviceprice>40.0</serviceprice>
            <textcode>1293</textcode >
            </service>
        </services>
    </price>
    <price>
    ...
...
```

and target mysql table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
    `code` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    `startdate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `enddate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `rentalprice` FLOAT(9,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and inserter data:

```
code        |startdate  |enddate    |rentalprice    |...
AD1700.100.1|2014-05-03 |2014-11-28 |               |
AD1700.100.2|2014-05-03 |2014-11-28 |               |
BG          |2011-10-15 |2011-11-25 |               |
```

My problem is column 'code' in price record. Db ignore childs, but price\services\code replace price\code , but I wand to using price* only without childs. Source XML can not by edited. code "BG" is bad becouse is not price\code but price\services[0]\code.

It can be set so that the SQL parser to ignore the same column name in the childs? Tahnks for the tip.

Tested on 10.0.10-MariaDB-1~wheezy-log

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to process your xml :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple XSLT or shell script to rename/remove the element `code` that is to be ignored and pipe the result forward to the database.

Comment: Good idea, I'd rather deal with everything directed sql server, if possible, ...but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: @pavex: why is it impossible (and what exactly)?

Comment: I do not want to perform preprocessing because the source XML document is large (more than 200 megabytes). I wanted to solve everything at MySQL. I'm concerned about performance when processing XML.

Comment: I understand. I know, it is not nice but still should work: cat my_big_file.xml | sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' | mysql_import. The oldstr/newstr-Regex should be then designed to rename/remoeve code-elements that are to be ignored. "mysql_import" is the mysql tool to load the data. This way will stream the contents and will not require the whole file to be loaded into the memory.